# Python 3.10 QuTip: AttributeError: can't set attribute 'format'

Tags: python, python-3.x, qutip

I'm trying to setup a simple `docker` container to make my code portable. Following is the docker container setup that I start with

```
docker run -it --name qutip_portble python:3.10.9-slim bash
```

Once the docker container starts, I install some packages as follows

```
pip install qutip
pip install matplotlib
```

Both of these install succesfully without any error. However, when I try to run the following import in python

```
import qutip
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qutip/__init__.py", line 106, in <module>
    from qutip.qobj import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qutip/qobj.py", line 2526, in <module>
    import qutip.superop_reps as sr
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qutip/superop_reps.py", line 74, in <module>
    _SINGLE_QUBIT_PAULI_BASIS = (identity(2), sigmax(), sigmay(), sigmaz())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qutip/operators.py", line 508, in identity
    return qeye(dims)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qutip/operators.py", line 488, in qeye
    return Qobj(fast_identity(size),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qutip/fastsparse.py", line 389, in fast_identity
    return fast_csr_matrix((data,ind,ptr),shape=(N,N))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qutip/fastsparse.py", line 55, in __init__
    self.format = 'csr'
AttributeError: can't set attribute 'format'
```

I get this error at the `import` stage before even writing any code of mine. Therefore, I'm assuming this is because of some setup issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I find that this error arises when using `scipy 1.11.0`, but using `scipy 1.10.1` is OK. You might file an issue to qutip.

Comment: Since I let `pip` take care of dependencies, I assumed it would install a compatible one. Thanks for the suggestion though, I'll give it a try and post update

Answer (score 1):

**Solution (thanks to [liginity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12420848/liginity)):** Use following commands while setting up the packages to explicitly install `scipy` version `1.10.1`

```
pip install scipy==1.10.1
pip install qutip
pip install matplotlib
```